# Dismissing (or popping) a NavigationController I added manually does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In my AppDelegate I have the following code which is executed after receiving a notification:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoPlayback"];

VideoPlaybackViewController *videoPlaybackViewController = (VideoPlaybackViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
videoPlaybackViewController.publishing = YES;
[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:navigationController animated:NO];
```

That successfully brings up the new ViewController and apparently adds it to the navigation stack, since I can use the back button on the navigation bar to go back and subsequently dismiss the view controller.

The problem is, I don't want to use the navigation bar. In fact, I would like to hide the back button. Unfortunately, when I try to dismiss the viewcontroller using the method(s) it should use, it does nothing. I've tried using both of these to dismiss the view controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to push a navigation controller into a navigation controller?

Comment: I didn't even notice that! That fixed my problem, thank you.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to push a navigation controller into a navigation controller, which won't end well.

```
[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:navigationController animated:NO];
```

probably needs to be changed to:

```
[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:videoPlaybackViewController animated:NO];
```